# Spring Data JPA @Query with Specification

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a requirement to create a REST api. Api allows user to provide dynamic search criteria in URL. For example, let say I have NOTES table with column as Note_ID, NOTE_TEXT, STATUS, PERSON_ID. This table is used to keep notes of every person.

Now I want my REST api to be as https://server:host/MyApi/Notes?search=NoteText=='My Java adventure'. API should provide all notes having NOTE_TEXT as 'My Java adventure'. Similarly user can provide status also in url and also he can use operators as LIKE. I was able to do it via rsql parser as mentioned in https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-rsql-fiql

Now I have additional requirement that based on user security person_id filter should be applied on query automatically.

I found that we can't have findBy method which can take Specification, Pageable and extra personId. For example I can't have a repository function as 
findByPersonId(Specification spec, Pageable page, Long personId);

I thought of using SpEL to use it, but then I found that if we use @Query annotation on findBy method, Specifications are ignored.

Seems like there is no way I can have Specification and @Query both. I need to add more clauses using specification only. In reality my where clause is very complex which I have to append and getting it with Specification seems to be difficult. Its something like
Select * from NOTES where exists (select 'x' from ABC a where n.person_id = a.person_id)

Is there a way I can write @Query and also have Specification working on top of it?

Ideally I have achieve a query like

```
select * from test.SCH_FORUM_THREAD t
where exists (select 'x' from test.FORUM_THREAD_ACCESS fta, school.SCH_GROUP_PERSON gp
                where gp.GROUP_ID = fta.GROUP_ID
                and t.THREAD_ID = fta.THREAD_ID
                and gp.PERSON_ID = :personId)
    or exists (select 'x' from test.FORUM_THREAD_ACCESS fta
                where fta.THREAD_ID = t.THREAD_ID
                and fta.PERSON_ID = :personId);
```

So there are two exists clauses with or condition. I was able to make second exists by following [How to write query(include subquery and exists) using JPA Criteria Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222868/how-to-write-queryinclude-subquery-and-exists-using-jpa-criteria-builder)

Now struggling with first exists as it has join also. Any idea how to do that with Specification. 
Also as there are two exists, does that mean I need two specifications. Can I achieve it in one specification.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379522/can-i-combine-a-query-definition-and-specifications-on-one-spring-data-jpa-repo

Comment: It is not possible to composite @Query and specification. Update your Specification code. So that we can have any other idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by creating a complex specification code. Something like

```
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<ForumThread> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
            Subquery<ForumThread> subQuery = query.subquery(ForumThread.class);
            Root<ForumThread> subRoot = subQuery.from(ForumThread.class);
            Join<ForumThreadAccess, GroupPerson> fragpjoin = subRoot.join("groupPersons");
            Predicate threadPredicate = builder.equal(root.get("threadId"), subRoot.get("threadId"));
            Predicate personPredicate = builder.equal(fragpjoin.get("personId"), personId); 
            subQuery.select(subRoot).where(threadPredicate, personPredicate);


            Predicate existsGroupPredicate = builder.exists(subQuery);


            Subquery<ForumThreadAccess> subQuery1 = query.subquery(ForumThreadAccess.class);
            Root<ForumThreadAccess> subRoot1 = subQuery1.from(ForumThreadAccess.class);
            Predicate threadPredicate1 = builder.equal(root.get("threadId"), subRoot1.get("threadId"));     
            Predicate personPredicate1 = builder.equal(subRoot1.get("personId"), personId); 
            subQuery1.select(subRoot1).where(threadPredicate1, personPredicate1);


            Predicate existsPersonPredicate = builder.exists(subQuery1);

            return builder.or(existsGroupPredicate,existsPersonPredicate);


        }
```

To make it work your entities should also have proper @OneToMany and @ManyToMany in place.

Thanks